# legacy_init_op in TensorFlow Serving

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've noticed every example on TensorFlow Serving uses `legacy_init_op` parameter in `SavedModelBuilder` but I have not found any clear explanations on what this is and why it is called **legacy**. Anyone knows the purpose of this argument?

Example:

```
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
          'predict_images':
              prediction_signature,
          tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
              classification_signature,
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tensorflow [Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/architecture_overview.html) uses lookup tables for embedding or vocabulary lookups. Previous version of tf < 1.2 initialization of tables need a separate op. So you need to use the `tf.tables_initializer()` separately to init the tables. In future version that operation will be combined within the ModelBundle.